# How to get last child node using java xml

Tags: java, xml

```
<section id="section1">
  <desc>Intestinal infectious diseases (A00-A09)</desc>
  <diag>
    <name>name1</name>
    <desc>Cholera</desc>
    <diag>
      <name>name1.1</name>
      <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae</desc>
      <inclusionTerm>
        <note>Classical cholera</note>
      </inclusionTerm>
    </diag>
    <diag>
      <name>name1.2</name>
      <desc>Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar eltor</desc>
      <inclusionTerm>
        <note>Cholera eltor</note>
      </inclusionTerm>
    </diag>
    <diag>
      <name>name1.3</name>
      <desc>Cholera, unspecified</desc>
    </diag>
  </diag>
  <diag>
      <name>name2</name>
      <desc>Other thrombophilia</desc>
      <inclusionTerm>
        <note>Other hypercoagulable states</note>
      </inclusionTerm>
      <excludes1>
        <note>diffuse or disseminated intravascular coagulation [DIC] (D65)</note>
        <note>heparin induced thrombocytopenia (HIT) (D75.82)</note>
        <note>hyperhomocysteinemia (E72.11)</note>
      </excludes1>
      <diag>
        <name>name2.1</name>
        <desc>Antiphospholipid syndrome</desc>
        <inclusionTerm>
          <note>Anticardiolipin syndrome</note>
          <note>Antiphospholipid antibody syndrome</note>
        </inclusionTerm>
        <excludes1>
          <note>anti-phospholipid antibody, finding without diagnosis (R76.0)</note>
          <note>anti-phospholipid antibody with hemorrhagic disorder (D68.312)</note>
          <note>lupus anticoagulant syndrome (D68.62)</note>
        </excludes1>
      </diag>          
    </diag>
```

Hi All,

From the abive xml I need to get last node from every main 'diag' node.
For example, the first diag tag has name, desc with three sub 'diag' node.
From that I need to get the sub three 'diag' if the node contains the sub node name like 'inclusionTerm'.

So, Finally I need the output like,

```
Name - name1.1
note - Classical cholera
Name - name1.2
note - Cholera eltor
```

friends, please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you need `name2` and `Other hypercoagulable states` ?

Comment: Because i need the least one valid in my program. In name2 'diag' i need name2.1 withn inclusionterm name.

Comment: You want `name2` but not the `Other hypercoagulable states` ?

Comment: You are saying get last node form every main diag node, but in the desired output in yrou question : why do you need `name1.1` and `Classical cholera` ?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear, please update the question with clear requirements.